# How do I use JQuery to return the value of the button clicked?

Tags: jquery, node.js

I want to store the value selected from a dropdown menu to run a query in the database to render the subsequent page.

How do I return only one of the values that's clicked from the dropdown menu?

The dropdown menu is created from the database:

```
            <div class="dropdown-content" id="account">
                <% for(var i=0; i < parentAccounts.rows.length; i++){ %>
                    <a href="/layout" >
                        <%- parentAccounts.rows[i].parent_account %>
                    </a>
                <% } %>
            </div>
```

The jquery script will return all the names:

```
        <script>
            $("#account").click(function(){
                var parent_account = ($(this).text());
                alert(parent_account);
            });
        </script>
```

There are only two unique items in the table at the moment.

Comment: You need value inside `a` tag which is clicked by user?

Comment: The a tags are dynamically updated based on the amount of items in the database

Comment: Change this `$("#account")` to this `$("#account > a")`

Comment: As i can see your code `a` tag is under for-loop so there will many such `a` tags ? which value you need then ? Currently when you do `$(this).attr('id')` will give you `account` as value .Not sure what do you need .

Comment: Yeah, I think you were onto the right thing - I needed to put the id="account" into the a ref. I was using another method to return the value before - Thanks @Swati

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the rendered html looks like this:

```
<div class="dropdown-content" id="account">
    <a href="/layout">1</a>
    <a href="/layout2">2</a>
</div>
```

In your code you handle a click on the `div` and not on the `a` element.

So all you need is this:

```
$("#account > a").click(function(e){
     var $a = $(this);
    // $a is the "a element"
    alert($a.text());
    
    // to prevent browser going to the link in href call 
    e.preventDefault();    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            <div class="dropdown-content" id="account">
                <% for(var i=0; i < parentAccounts.rows.length; i++){ %>
                    <a href="/layout" >
                        <%- parentAccounts.rows[i].parent_account %>
                    </a>
                <% } %>
            </div>
```

```
            $("#account > a").click(function(){
                var parent_account = ($(this).text());
                alert(parent_account);
            });
```